# 7 segment display orientation problem

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

So i am completely new on this topic. i have a problem which looks something like this.

i have a  light which is designed with a 7 segment display which gives the reading of various parameters . the light's orientation by default is vertical with display on bottom. Problem is if we rotate the light by 180 degrees , the result would be display on the top and light on the bottom in an inverted vertical orientation. the light and display would function properly but the digits will also be flipped vertically. I am looking for solution to this, i want that the 7 segment display should be displaying figures properly according to the orientation . eg:- if its in default orientation then 7 segment display must also be in default, but when light is vertically rotated by 180 degree , the display must change in such a way to display result properly. I would really appreciate if somebody could come up with an idea to overcome this problem.

and the last one is really easy , what would be the best way to break the circuit if the input exceed 225 volts ?.

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

So for the 7-segment display, simply re'number' the segments connections a..g to correspond to the new orientation and change the wiring to suit. The pin that goes to the 'f' segment in normal orientation becomes 'c' and so on.

Of course the digit commons will be flipped left-to-right if it's a multiplexed display, and the decimal points will be at the top left rather than the bottom right so other changes may be necessary.

[image]

Your second question is unrelated, but there are industrial adjustable voltage relays that can be used for this purpose (to cut power when voltage is too low or too high).